# Authenticate ftp users on mysql through secure channel

Tags: mysql, ssh, ftp, authentication, cluster

I've to face this problem regarding security:

some sFTP servers (proftpd) in a dmz that need to authenticate users against a mysql (native cluster|percona cluster|MariaDB cluster) through a secure channel (encrypted psw is not enough).
Seems that proftpd can't connect to mysql (cluster) through ssh.
Any advice about solving this issue?
Thanks for your time
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up stunnel to create an encrypted tunnel between the FTP server and the mysql servers. Then have proftp connect to the tunnel end on localhost.

Comment: something like `ssh -f user@dbserver -L 3306:dbserver:3306 -N`   then modify proftpd.conf to point to the server on localhost, (might need to adjust table permissions as well

Comment: SSH requires you to have a user that allows SSH logins on the mysql server. That's why I suggested stunnel instead.

Comment: yes I know, but OP asked about ssh..

Comment: They wrote "proftpd **can't** connect to mysql through ssh". Which, again, is why I suggested an alternative.

Comment: Maybe my question was not perfectly posed, anyway both answer/comments are of value for me.
Thank you